# How do I call the Capybara input `.set` method on the "Selenium::WebDriver::Element" instance returned from "execute_script"?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I use Capybara.
I call the `execute_script` to execute the JS code that returns some data including DOM nodes.
Some of these nodes are `<input>`s and I need to call the `.set` on them like I usually do when I search for them like `find("input")`.

But I get the

```
NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `set' for #<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:
```

because it's not the `Capybara::Node::Element` class.

Can I somehow cast the element to `Capybara::Node::Element` class to be able to call the method or should I do something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn’t be using `execute_script` to return things. If you instead use `evaluate_script` when returning items they should get wrapped automatically